# Array in for loop

Tags: java, arrays

I'm new to stack overflow so sorry for anything that might consider me a newbie.
I understand java to a certain degree, however, i am stuck on one thing i hope you guys can help me on.

I am in the process of making a floating point simulator and i am struggling on this section of the code.

I need the next part of the array [1] to reach the total *length of the mantissa* my knowledge with arrays in java are not exactly the best so any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

```
public float toDecimal()
{

    /**
     * Convert Exponent and find shift
     */

    char[] mantissaCharArray = mantissa.toCharArray();
    int mantissaLength = mantissaCharArray.length;
    float[] mantissaMultiplierArray = new float[mantissaLength];

    mantissaMultiplierArray[0]= 1;

    for (mantissaMultiplierArray[1];mantissaCharArray;mantissaMultiplierArray++)
    {
        //for loop to cover array from [1] to the lengthmantissa
    }


    //each one multiply current 
}
```

Comment: You should probably start with the [Arrays](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html) section of the Java tutorial and the on about the [for](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html) statement

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
for (int i=(int)mantissaMultiplierArray[0];i< mantissaCharArray.length;i++)
{
//
}
```

`mantissaMultiplierArray[0]` will return float value.

Answer (score 0):

So you want to run through each element of an array? You are right with the for loop, just wrote it wrong. It should go something like this;

```
for(int i = (int)mantissaMultiplierArray[0]; i < mantissaCharArray.length; i++)
{
    System.out.println(mantissaMultiplierArray[i]);
}
```

Let me explain the setup of this for loop a bit more;

- You are setting an integer value i to the first value of `mantissaMultiplierArray`. You are also parsing it as an int because it is a float, hence the `(int)`
- You give `i` a limitation - the total size of the `mantissaCharArray`
- increment `i`

In the for loop I have it set to print out the values of the `mantissaMultiplierArray` for each value of `i`, but yu can do whatever you want inside of it.